# how to get accountid with username poolid and clientid in cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

i am trying to write a boto3 client to get temporary keys with help of sts, but sts requires ARN which requires accountId and roleArn which in turn requires credentials to fetch.
i only have username & password (which is provided by the user), poolid and client id.
is there anyways to fetch account id based on just the above?

Comment: Creating the temporary keys is done with some sort of `admin` account, I assume. You can call `sts.get_caller_identity()` (using that `admin` account) to show the AccountId